# Is possible to build -168 dBm amplifer?

Tags: power, rf, wireless, radio, receiver

we know that GPS receiver can reach sensitivty of -168dBm, and also it is possible to make receivers with similar sensetitvity can operate at another bands/frequencies .

but I just want to know if possible to build amplifier with input of -168 dBm ? I want  increase signal power at some -90s dBm range to make the system able to receive high bitrate at very weak signals "-160s dBm" .

I know the noise will also amplified , but the SNR still unchanged or slightly.

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can amplify anything you want. In fact, any amplifier is just fine with a -168 dBm input, provided 168 dBm isn't over its maximum input power specification (which I guess is true of just about *every* amplifier). If you want a -168 dBm input to become -90 dBm, then you need a 78 dB amplifier. That's nothing special.

However, that won't do anything to improve your situation. Every GPS receiver already has an amplifier. The problem is, as you mention, that the SNR is unchanged at best. In practice, an amplifier has active electronics that adds additional noise. This additional noise is usually specified as a [noise figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_figure). It isn't the low power of the GPS signal that's problematic, it's that the signal-to-noise ratio is insufficient to reliably extract the signal from the noise. Amplification doesn't change that.

Comment: However, the GPS signal has very specific characteristics that permit it to be detected at very low levels, even below the background noise.  It can be correlated with a reference signal.  This process adds significant processing gain which directly increases the effective signal-to-noise ratio.  This is not true for a random low level signal whose waveshape and other characteristics are not known.

Comment: but I didnt find any commircal  amplifiers has input range of -168 dBm ?!

I read about some GPS receivers can distinguish signal at noise levels up to 30 dB , like u-blox .

Comment: http://www.u-blox.com/images/downloads/Product_Docs/u-blox%20anti-jamming_whitepaper_(GPS-X-09008).pdf

"This special jamming-mitigation method requires considerable processing
power, which u-blox 5 / 6 supplies with an ARM® processor. Under control
of this processor, this proprietary combination of hardware and software
can reduce jamming signals by 30 dB compared to conventional products"

Comment: "Anti-jamming" usually refers to the reduction of a small number of specific, higher strength signals in the same frequency range as GPS so that they do not affect position accuracy.  How that works would be a different question.

Comment: @Barry That's true, but that doesn't mean GPS has some magical property that allows it to be detected at the same SNR if the overall power is higher. For any modulation, no matter how robust, there is a minimum SNR at which it can be detected. Amplification of signal and noise doesn't increase SNR.

Comment: *"... it's that the signal is indistinguishable from atmospheric and electronic noise."* That isn't true, and that's the point that @Barry was making. If you know what you're looking for, the signal is *very* distinguishable from noise, and that processing gain is what allows the usable SNR to be negative.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for your comment.  My point is that straight amplification does not increase SNR but there are signal processing techniques that utilize the known characteristics of the signal to effectively increase its level with respect to the noise.  Cross correlation, with which I am very familiar since my company applied it in a passive sonar application, is one of these techniques. We were able to detect the presence of the noise radiated by a submarine when that noise was more than 20 dB below the level of the ambient background noise.

Comment: @Barry What about 30 dB below? 40 dB below? Surely you don't have an infinite detection sensitivity in the presence of noise, and at some point the *signal becomes indistinguishable from the noise*, right? Does amplification change that in any way?

Comment: Fun, If what @Barry is talking about is lockin (like) detection, then I agree it can find signals buried in noise.  But it does this (mostly) by a lot of signal averaging.  Long time constants wrt the modulation frequency.  And I think most of the noise reduction is just a narrowing of the bandwidth. (not that lockin's aren't totally cool.)

Comment: The implication of the gps performance claim and the physical noise floor is that the bandwidth (of the correlation) is on the order of a Hz or two.  But then, all one is trying to do at that level is phase lock a model to reality over a substantial evaluation time - ie, look for small errors.  If the model is more than slightly off, a time-consuming search will ensue.

Answer (score 3):

-168 dBm is very tiny and equivalent to ~1.7 nV RMS in a 50 ohm system over a measly and pathetic bandwidth of only 3.8 Hz at about 30degC.

If that bandwidth is no good then you'll have to start cooling the radio receiver front end. For instance a 50 ohm resistor generates -168 dBm when cooled to -100 degC but with a slightly improved bandwidth of 6.6 Hz.

Realistically, the "best" formula around that I know of is this: -

Minimum signal power = -154dBm + 10.log\$_{10}\$(data rate)

At a data rate of 1 Hz, mimimum power a receiver needs at about 27degC is -154dBm. At 10 bps this is -144dBm and at 100 bps it's -134dBm.

You can probably see the trend; every tenfold increase in BW requires a signal power that is 10dB more.

At 1M bps, the receiver requires -94 dBm etc...

So, it looks like cooling is the only option but, unfortunately, even when cooled at -272 degC, a 50 ohm resistor will produce -168 dBm over only a 1kHz bandwidth.

Comment: Also see the related [Shannon-Hartley theorm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem).

Comment: that is mean amplifying -168 dBm to -94 dBm does not improve data rate , right ?

Comment: Again, it's about amplifying noise and signal equals no net benefit.